# What is the electron configuration for Og with a charge of 2-?

Tags: atoms, electronic-configuration

I was writing a cool program that determines the electron configuration of elements for me, and I wondered what would happen if you went over 118 — the "limit" of my program.  So, what is the electron configuration after you go over 118 electrons?

Comment: I'm curious how do you handle Cu for instance. As a free atom in outer space, or as the metal in a solid? Or can you program do both?

Comment: @MaxW I'm only in 9th grade, so I haven't really learned that much about electron configurations. Do the configurations really differ for Cu based on its environment? My program takes the input of however many electrons an atom has, and spits out the electron notation along with the noble gas notation. So if the Cu in outer space has x electrons and the Cu "as the metal in a solid" has y electrons, I can input both x and y into my program, and it will give me  the correct (to my knowledge) notation for both x and y.

Comment: Yes. Cu in a metal is more like a Cu+2 ion. A gas of Cu atoms in free space doesn't conduct electricity. A solid piece of copper will.

Comment: @10Replies Not that it's necessarily relevant, but how does your program calculate the lowest energy configuration? Does it take account of 'anomalous' electron configurations such as chromium and copper?

Comment: @10-Replies - Great you're thinking about chemistry. The Periodic Table is the ultimate lego kit.

Comment: @bon I'm not sure if I understand what you are saying... But it uses the  Aufbau principle, the Pauli exclusion principle. And it doesn't know about special cases where the rules don't apply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [SCF Relativistic Hartree–Fock Calculations on the Superheavy Elements 118–131](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jcp/53/6/10.1063/1.1674338) J. Chem. Phys. 53, 2397 (1970), for neutral atoms:

119 $8s$

120 $8s^2$

121 $8p8s^2$

122 $7d8p8s^2$

123 $6f7d8p8s^2$

124 $6f^38p8s^2$

125 $5g6f^38p8s^2$

126 $5g^26f^28p^28s^2$

127 $5g^36f^28p^28s^2$

128 $5g^46f^28p^28s^2$

129 $5g^56f^28p^28s^2$

130 $5g^66f^28p^28s^2$

131 $5g^76f^28p^28s^2$

Later calculations reported in [Electronic Configurations of Superheavy Elements](http://journals.jps.jp/doi/abs/10.1143/JPSJ.65.3175) J. Phys. Soc. Jpn. 65, pp. 3175-3179 (1996) are different starting with element 122:

122 $8p^28s^2$

123 $6f7d8p8s^2$

124 $6f^28p^28s^2$

125 $6f^48p8s^2$

126 $5g6f^48p8s^2$

127 $5g^26f^38p^28s^2$

128 $5g^36f^38p^28s^2$

129 $5g^46f^38p^28s^2$

130 $5g^56f^38p^28s^2$

131 $5g^66f^38p^28s^2$

However, [Electronic structure of eka-thorium (element 122)
compared with thorium](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-4075/35/7/307/meta) *J. Phys. B: At. Mol. Opt. Phys.* 35 (2002) 1693–1700 finds:

122 $7d8p8s^2$

specifically agreeing with the 1970 paper and disagreeing with the 1996 paper.

See [A suggested periodic table up to Z[=]172, based on Dirac–Fock
calculations on atoms and ions](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/2011/CP/C0CP01575J#!divAbstract) Phys. Chem. Chem. Phys., 2011, 13, 161–168 for additional information.